# Ceiling function in R is inaccurate (sometimes)

Tags: r, rounding, ceil

I am trying to round up a number x to be divisible by a number m. Using the following function from previous post on SO:

```
roundUP = function(x,m) 
{
    return(m * ceiling(x/m))
}
```

But, when I input **x = 0.28** and **m = 0.005**, the function outputs 0.285 when the result should be 0.28.

When I tried `ceiling(0.28/0.005)` it outputs 57 when the result should be 56 since 56 is already a whole number. Can anyone explain if is this happening and is this an error from Ceiling function?

Answer (score 5):

The issue has to do with floating point arithmetic. You can find some details about this [here](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f).

Walk through the code below and it should shed some light on what's going on.

```
0.28/0.005  # Console displays 56
0.28/0.005 == 56  # returns FALSE. Why?
print(0.28/0.005, digits = 18)  # 56.0000000000000071

# Solution?
roundUP = function(x, m) 
{
  return(m * ceiling(round(x/m, 9)))
}
```

Also, note the **Warning** section within `?ceiling`

> The realities of computer arithmetic can cause unexpected results,
>   especially with floor and ceiling. For example, we ‘know’ that
>   floor(log(x, base = 8)) for x = 8 is 1, but 0 has been seen on an R
>   platform. It is normally necessary to use a tolerance.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it. And do you know why this problem doesn't happen in Excel?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't.

Answer (score -3):

In R,

**floor(x)** function rounds to the nearest integer that’s smaller than x.

**ceiling(x)** function rounds to the nearest integer that’s larger than x.

So whatever be the value after the decimal point, R considers the next integer (before/after).

If you want `56` as the output, you must use `floor(0.28/0.005)`.

Comment: Your definitions of floor and ceiling are incorrect.  See ?floor and ?ceiling

Comment: Or would it be correct when it said, `floor(x)` function rounds to the smallest integer not less than `x` & `ceiling(x)` function rounds to the largest integer not greater than `x`

Comment: Shreyas you have that backwards. Even if you get the definitions right, I think you're missing the point.  Do this.. What do you get in R when you do `ceiling(56)`?  Now what is 0.28/0.005?  And what do you get when you do `ceiling(0.28/0.005)`?  Notice the difference.

Comment: yeah...got it.
so as per your line of code `print(0.28/0.005, digits = 18)  # 56.0000000000000071` 
ceiling of it returns `57` because of the value after the decimal point.
Right?

Comment: Also i would like to know, why my regular calculator says `56` and R says `56.0000000000000071`? Is it because of so-called tolerance `.Machine$double.eps ^ 0.5.`? If so, then I need to study `tolerance`. Is it with respect to mathematics/computing?